# JavaScript Unexpected Identifier Error Code

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am having trouble with getting this code to run correctly. It says I have an unexpected identifier on the line beginning with "myBmiCalc."

The first output sentence works if I get rid of the added myBmiCalc function but I need to calculate my BMI using the data from the person object.

```
<head>

    <title>Person object and BMI calculator</title> 

</head>

<body>

    <center> 

        <h2>My BMI Calculator</h2>
        <p id="person"> </p>
        <p id="myBmi"> </p>

        <script>
            let person ={

                firstName : "Dave",
                lastName : "Rand", 
                height: 58, 
                weight: 150,
                personScript : function() {
                    return (this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " is " + this.height + " inches tall " + " and weighs " + this.weight + " pounds"); 
                } 

                myBmiCalc : function() {
                    return("And, his BMI is " + (weight/(height*height)*703)); 

                }

            }; 

            document.getElementById('person').innerHTML = person.personScript();
            document.getElementById('myBmi').innerHTML = person.myBmiCalc();

        </script>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after `personScript: function() {...},`

Comment: missing a comma before 'myBmiCalc:'.

Comment: @brbcoding Please don't forget to vote to close for "*simple typographical error*"